# Does the Christofides algorithm ensure this inequality?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a finite metric space. Let $C$ be a Hamiltonian cycle (over $X$) outputted by Christofide's algorithm. Also, let $K$ be a minimum spanning tree. I am aware that Christofide's algorithm is a $\frac{3}{2}$ approximation algorithm. But does the following also holds

$$l(C) \le \frac{3}{2} l(K)$$

where $l(.)$ denotes the cost, interpreted in a natural way. I do not see why it should hold, but
[this](https://ur.booksc.me/book/7553484/af4a2c) paper seems to use this as a fact in theorem $5$.

Comment: The claim is false for general metric spaces. Take a path on $n$ vertices with unit edge lengths, and $d$ is the shortest path metric induced by this graph. The MST cost is $(n-1)$ while the optimum TSP cost is $2(n-1)$.

Comment: The OP does seem to be correct that a line in the proof of Theorem 5 in that paper states that the cycle C has total weight at most (3/2) times the weight of the spanning tree.  And Chandra does seem to be right that this doesn't hold in general.  So I think OP's question is reasonable.  Here is a doi link to the paper: https://doi.org/10.1007/s003730070012

Comment: Yes, seems like that paper mis-states Christofide's result to be $l(C) \leq (3/2) l(K)$, when the result is only $l(C) \leq (3/2) OPT$ where OPT is the optimal TSP solution.